# sandbox-exec file-write behaves unexpectedly

Tags: sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I have a rules file like this

```
(version 1)
(deny default)
...
(allow file-write* (regex "/Users/thomas/Desktop"))
```

When I use it on app A, it works fine (the app can write to the desktop) but when used on app B, it doesn't work. So I made a test app (app C), a simple cocoa app that just writes a dummy string to a file, and it still doesn't work.
If I replace `(allow file-write* (regex "/Users/thomas/Desktop"))` with `(allow file-write*)` it works on app B and C too, so I know that's the only thing that's wrong.

So I really don't understand what's going on. How can it work for app A but not for B or C? Especially given that:

- allowing all works (so I know the regex is the culprit)
- app C is minimal and is not a blackbox
- I tried tons of different variations: `literal` instead of regex, `"^/Users/thomas/Desktop"`, `"^/Users/thomas/Desktop/"` , `"^/Users/thomas/Desktop/*"`, ...